# Delete trailing whitespace, alternative to substitute command

Tags: vim

To delete trailing whitespace on a line or across a file I can do:

```
:[range]s/\s\+$//
```

However, I was wondering for a single line in normal mode if there's an easier approach, for example if the line is:

```
Hi, I am a line           |
```

And my cursor is past the e, is there a more generic command than doing `dTe` in normal mode? The next best I could find was `dg_`, but that goes one too far. And then, one more option might be `gElD`.

Comment: `I was wondering for a single line in normal mode` Just make a mapping.

Comment: @Matt sure, how would you do this yourself with a mapping, `gelD`, or something else?

Comment: Map to `:s//` command

Comment: @Matt -- got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generic way without `:substitute`

Use <kbd>diw</kbd> to delete multiple whitespace (including tabs) while the cursor is on one of the whitespaces (like in the example).

This works for any whitespace sequence: trailing, leading, etc.

Use <kbd>dw</kbd> to delete from the cursor to the end of the sequence. This is useful when you want to re-indent a line or fix alignment.

As this is independent of the first/last character of the previous/next word this is the most generic way.

### Using a mapping with `:substitute`

Use `nmap <leader>tr :%s/\s\+$//` to remove all trailing whitespace in the whole buffer by pressing <kbd>\tr</kbd> (assuming the original `mapleader`)<sup>1</sup>.

Replace `tr` with what ever suits you best.

Omit the the `%` in the mapping to make it only work on the current line.

--

As a side note: Use `set list listchars=trail:·` to show trailing whitespace (replace `·` with any character you like).

--

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Removing all whitespace may not be what you want, especially when using a version control system and the file contains whitespace not added by yourself.</sub>